# Dependeny Injection and Partial class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a partial class that is generated by code generator

```
public partial class PersonRepository: IPersonRepository
{
    public string Method1(){...}
    public string Method2(){...}
    //...
}
```

I would like to extend this class and be able to use Dependency Injection

I tried it this way

```
public interface IPersonRepositoryExtended : IPersonRepository
{
    public string Method3(){...}
}

public class PersonRepositoryExtended: PersonRepository, IPersonRepositoryExtended
{
    public string Method3(){...}
    //...
}
```

then for DI I mapped `IPersonRepositoryExtended` to `PersonRepositoryExtended`,  is there a better way of doing this?

Should I create a partial class of `PersonRepository` and if I do so how does the interface mapping work?

Comment: You don't necessarily need the `PersonRepositoryExtended` class nor the 'extended' interface. Simply add another file where 'public partial class PersonRepository` and add your methods there.

Comment: When you use the word _extend_, do you use it in its technical meaning, as in _derive_ or _inherit_, or are you rather looking for how to create another part of the partial class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there:

create the extended interface like you had planned

```
public interface IPersonRepositoryExtended : IPersonRepository
{
    string Method3();
}
```

and then continue with `PersonRepository` partial class. No need for the extended class as you had before.

```
public partial class PersonRepository: IPersonRepositoryExtended
{
    public string Method3(){...}
}
```

you will then inject the extended interface where needed.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(IPersonRepositoryExtended dependency) { ... }
}
```

the mapping would be between `IPersonRepositoryExtended` and `PersonRepository`.

Just remember that the partial classes need to belong to the same project.